# Creating a static global varible that I can increment in subprojects

Tags: gradle

I have a project with many sub-projects.

In the parent project I need to define a variable for a `port`. Each time a subproject executes a particular task, I need to increment the port (thereby ensuring that the port number is never used twice as I run in --parallel).

How do I do this?

### update for clarity

So for a project structure like this

```
parent -
       |->sub-project-1
       |  
       |->sub-project-2
```

The parent project should define the initial port number.

```
  project.ext.portNumber = 4200 //set a global port number somehow
```

In each sub-project I want to use this port number

```
  project.portNumber++; //increment in some way
  println "${project.name} is using port: ${project.portNumber}"
```

So running `gradlew build` on the `parent` project would output:

```
sub-project-1 is using port: 4201
sub-project-2 is using port: 4202
```

If I run `gradlew build` while inside `parent/sub-project-2` I would get

```
sub-project-2 is using port: 4201
```

As each project builds I need the portNumber to be like static property in java, ie. it is available to all sub-projects and does not get reset.

Comment: I think this question might be considered too general.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by _Each time a sub-project executes a particular task_? Is it for the same task for all relevant sub-project or each sub project can have one or more tasks that needs to get a new port number?

Comment: @AmnonShochot have updated for clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly then you need each sub-project to be assigned a port number, regardless of whether you're running a full build from the root project or from within some of the sub-project.

Therefore, you'll have to calculate the port number for all projects in every execution of gradle.

The following code:

```
ext.portNumber = 4200
gradle.projectsEvaluated { g ->
    g.rootProject.subprojects { p ->
        p.ext.portNumber = gradle.rootProject.portNumber++
        println "$p.name [$p.portNumber]"
    }
}
```

Executed against the following project structure

```
parent -
       |->projA -
                |->projA1
                |->projA2
       |->projB
```

Yielded the following output whether it was executed from the root project or from one of the sub-project:

```
projA [0]
projB [1]
projA1 [2]
projA2 [3]
```

One note - I admit that I did not check this solution extensively with the `--parallel` flag. However, as the `projectsEvaluated` hook is called before the task graph is being populated it is possible that the --parallel does not affect this configuration. In case it does then I believe that you can just sync the access to the root project `portNumber` by using any of java standard synchronization mechanism.